# Execute mongo query with parameter through shell scripts, is it possible?

Tags: bash, mongodb, shell, parameter-passing

I don't know if this is even possible, I can see that there might be issues with using bash parameters in a mongo eval query. What I'm trying to do is to update documents in mongo where a value **date** is greater than todays date.

Example: Today's date is less(<) than tomorrows date, thus update field X of same document.

I've got the following, but I'm wondering how to pass the date variable to the mongo query. Is it even possible? Is there another way to Rome?

```
#!/bin/sh
today="$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')"

mongo db --eval 'db.Scheme.update({"FutureDate":{$gte: $today}},{$set:{"X":"$today"}});'
```

Alternately I've tried to switch $today with ***new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)***   but are unable to perform the query.

Help or constructive feedback is much appreciated, thanks! :)

Comment: shell variables don't get expanded in single quotes. Try enclosing your variable inside double quotes like `command 'previous'"$var"'next"`

Comment: Thanks @user000001! Worked as a charm, hm, dont know why I didn't try that, any idea on how I can $today as a real date value? and not as string?

Like with javascript, 
var from = ISODate("2011-11-24")

Any idea on how I can do the same in shell/bash?

Comment: I don't think that you can do that from bash. You'll probably have to do it from mongo, but I don't know how...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came to a solution to my problem, it solves (I would say 95%) of my case. I found that I didn't need to pass a parameter although I was able to do it using '"$variable"' inside the mongo query while testing (see To pass variable for more).

**My query solution is below** (does not include passing variable):

db.Scheme.update({"FutureDate":{$gte: new Date()}},{$set
:{"X":Value}},{multi:true});

{multi:true} allows all documents in Scheme to be looped.

**Full query in script**

## !/bin/sh

mongo databaseurl:port/database -u username -p password --eval 'db.Scheme.update({"FutureDate":{$gte: new Date()}},{$set
:{"X":Value}},{multi:true});'

**To pass variable (example):**

## !/bin/sh

Value="Example"

mongo databaseurl:port/database -u username -p password --eval 'db.Scheme.update({"FutureDate":{$gte: new Date()}},{$set
:{"X":'"$Value"'}},{multi:true});'

***Hope it can help someone else as well! Thanks user000001 for help along the way :)***

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
#!/bin/bash
Value="Example"

mongo databaseurl:port/database -u username -p password --eval  \ 
"db.Scheme.update({\"FutureDate\":{$gte: new Date()}},{$set :{\"X\":\"${Value}\"}},\{multi:true});"
```